# WPF Resize UserControl with aspect ratio

Tags: wpf, resize, aspect-ratio

I have a UserControl and that UserControl has to be resized with aspect ratio. 
That means: width:height = 2:1.
Currently I am using this code:

```
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
    {
        if (ActualWidth == 0 || ActualHeight == 0) return arrangeBounds;
        base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeBounds);
        double ratio = 2;

        if (Parent != null)
        {
            var size = new Size(arrangeBounds.Height * ratio, arrangeBounds.Height);

            double containerWidth = ((FrameworkElement)Parent).ActualWidth;
            if (containerWidth < size.Width)
            {
                double newHeight = arrangeBounds.Height * (containerWidth / size.Width);
                canvas.Width = newHeight * ratio;
                canvas.Height = newHeight;
            }
            else
            {
                canvas.Width = size.Height * ratio;
                canvas.Height = size.Height;
            }
        }

        return arrangeBounds;
    }
```

But it is not really working. That means it works but not every time. If I max. the window it sometimes does not get resized, so its a bit "random" if the control gets resized. So if someone would have a better solution if would be very nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit late, but I recently came across the same problem and since I did not find a good solution I decided to write my own layout control/decorator and wrote a blog post about it here:

http://coding4life.wordpress.com/2012/10/15/wpf-resize-maintain-aspect-ratio/

Basically my solution was to overwrite both `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride`. So far it works very nicely in all of the common containers and I didn't encounter any problems like you described.

I recommend reading the post, where you find a working decorator control, but the most important methods are these:

```
   protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   {
      if (Child != null)
      {
         constraint = SizeToRatio(constraint, false);
         Child.Measure(constraint);

         if(double.IsInfinity(constraint.Width)
            || double.IsInfinity(constraint.Height))
         {
            return SizeToRatio(Child.DesiredSize, true);
         }

         return constraint;
      }

      // we don't have a child, so we don't need any space
      return new Size(0, 0);
   }

   protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
   {
      if (Child != null)
      {
         var newSize = SizeToRatio(arrangeSize, false);

         double widthDelta = arrangeSize.Width - newSize.Width;
         double heightDelta = arrangeSize.Height - newSize.Height;

         double top = 0;
         double left = 0;

         if (!double.IsNaN(widthDelta)
            && !double.IsInfinity(widthDelta))
         {
            left = widthDelta/2;
         }

         if (!double.IsNaN(heightDelta)
            && !double.IsInfinity(heightDelta))
         {
            top = heightDelta/2;
         }

         var finalRect = new Rect(new Point(left, top), newSize);
         Child.Arrange(finalRect);
      }

      return arrangeSize;
   }

   public Size SizeToRatio(Size size, bool expand)
   {
      double ratio = AspectRatio;

      double height = size.Width / ratio;
      double width = size.Height * ratio;

      if (expand)
      {
         width = Math.Max(width, size.Width);
         height = Math.Max(height, size.Height);
      }
      else
      {
         width = Math.Min(width, size.Width);
         height = Math.Min(height, size.Height);
      }

      return new Size(width, height);
   }
```

I hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 5):

The most straightforward solution would be to Bind the Height directly to the Width, through a value converter.

Comment: the main problem will be that the height can get too big. Because if the width of the container is 3000px and the height 600px i will scale the height up to 1500px. So it will be tooooooo big.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your Control with a `ViewBox` and set the `ViewBox.Stretch` to `Uniform`. You can also restrict on MaxWidth and MaxHeight that way.

> [More Info on the Stretch-Enumeration @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch.aspx)
>
> [How to apply Stretch @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752301.aspx)