# Expanding square control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have to layout some content squarely. Wanted container must expand to provided by its parent space, but hold 1:1 width:height ratio. Which control meets my requirements? How can it be done?

Comment: http://coding4life.wordpress.com/2012/10/15/wpf-resize-maintain-aspect-ratio/ and related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657453/wpf-resize-usercontrol-with-aspect-ratio

Comment: Answers in the second reference doesn't solve control auto expanding problem. Using SizeChanged event you have't got access to provided by parent space's width and height.

Comment: Bind the `Height` to the `ActualWidth` or viceversa.

Comment: I have already tried it, but in result content is properly scaled only in one direction. Consider parent spaces, which ratios are (e.g.) 2:1 and 1:2.